# Php save page id

Tags: php, web-services, function, functional-programming

What is a function that saves the page id? let me explain it for example I am in a lesson and want to save the current lesson,so when I came later to see where I left. Help me!

Comment: What is a "Page ID"?  A URL paramater?  Example:  `http://example.com/file.php?id=39215`

Comment: Can you provide more info?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Session`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), session is an array that You can store information in it, You must save every `user_id` or `lesson_id` in a data storage(like database) and can access information of user by its id.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the page id in a [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) on the user computer and read from it whenever the user reload the page. So whenever the user moves to the next lesson you just update the cookie with the new lesson's page id.
Basically when the page loads, you should try to read the cookie if it exists and resume at the page id stored in the cookie. If the cookie does not exists then you can assume the user is a new user and store the first lesson page id and move on from there.